# Framework for "Stress Testing" Excel models

Tags: excel, vba

I have a "black box" excel model with 1 sheet.  It has 2 inputs, which are named ranges "Input1" and "Input2", and one output, which is a named range "Output".  I wrote a macro to test the sensitivity of this model to variations in it's inputs, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do this:

```
Sub LoopMacro()

Dim outrow As Integer
outrow = 1

For i = 1 To 10 Step 0.5
    Range("Input1").Value = i

    For j = 1 To 10 Step 0.5
        Range("Input2").Value = j

        Output outrow
        outrow = outrow + 1

    Next j
Next i
End Sub

Sub Output(outrow As Integer)

Sheets("Output").Cells(outrow, 1) = Range("Input1").Value
Sheets("Output").Cells(outrow, 2) = Range("Input2").Value
Sheets("Output").Cells(outrow, 3) = Range("Output").Value

End Sub
```

The problem with this macro is that it requires a for loop for each input variable, and would get rather tedious if I had more than a few inputs.  I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to code this such that I can define `n` inputs (named ranged "Input1", "Input1", to "Inputn"), along with their min and max values, and have the macro automatically loop through the relevant values of Input1-Inputn

Comment: Do the inputs need to be nested as you've shown, or can they be linear?

Comment: @Doug Glancy I'm not sure what you mean.  In the example I showed, I wanted to test every possible combination of "Input1" and "Input2" in the ranges I defined.

Comment: Look at Excel "data tables" under the what-if analysis menu: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/calculate-multiple-results-by-using-a-data-table-HP010072656.aspx. Also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640336/using-a-sheet-in-an-excel-user-defined-function/4640866#4640866

Comment: I was referring to the nested loop, with j inside of i.  It doesn't seem necessary.  It looks like each loop could follow the previous.  At any rate, I think @jtolle's suggestion is good.

Comment: If it works for you, maybe you can post an answer here and accept it for completeness sake.

Comment: The issues with sensitivities aren't so much the mechanics of applying them, it is the reasonableness of the input variables. In your case you are assuming a uniform distribution, should the inputs be log-normal, Poisson, skewed etc. If they are uniform go the "Data Table" route suggested by jtolle, if not then you should be looking at code that can handle uncertainty distributions. A good professional package is [Crytal Ball](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/bus-int/crystalball/index.html)

Comment: @Doug Glancy: In my example, I want to know the interaction of "Input1" and "Input2", not just their individual effects.

Comment: @brettdj: Thanks for the suggestion.  The next step would be monte carlo simulation, either using crystal ball or VBA.  For the problem I have at hand, I'm just trying to get a rough idea of the min and max possible values for "Output", given a range of possible values for "Input1" and "Input2".

Comment: @jtolle: Thanks for the data tables suggestion.  I'll check it out.

Comment: I'll just note that the *values* you use for your independent parameters with a data table can themselves come from a formula or any other source, so you're not limited to a uniform distribution...

Comment: @Zach, sorry.  I think "brain-fart" is the technical term to explain my lack of understanding.  It of course makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but this may be what you're looking for: just modify the arrays which contain the parameter names and value ranges.

```
Sub TestModelInputs()

    Dim shtModel As Worksheet, shtResults As Worksheet
    Dim arrNames, arrMin, arrMax, arrStep, arrVals, x
    Dim rw As Long, lb, ub, n, incr As Boolean

    '###modify input parameters here
    arrNames = Array("Input1", "Input2", "Input3")
    arrMin = Array(1, 1, 1)
    arrMax = Array(4, 5, 6)
    arrStep = Array(1, 1, 1)
    '###done with parameter setup

    Set shtModel = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Model")
    Set shtResults = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results")

    rw = 1
    arrVals = arrMin
    lb = LBound(arrNames)
    ub = UBound(arrNames)
    n = (ub - lb) + 1
    shtResults.UsedRange.ClearContents

    Do             
        rw = rw + 1
        For x = lb To ub
            shtModel.Range(arrNames(x)).Value = arrVals(x)
        Next x

        With shtResults.Rows(rw)
            .Cells(1).Resize(1, n).Value = arrVals
            .Cells(n + 1).Value = shtModel.Range("Output").Value
        End With

        For x = lb To ub
            If arrVals(x) < arrMax(x) Then
                arrVals(x) = arrVals(x) + arrStep(x)
                Exit For
            Else
                If x = ub Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    arrVals(x) = arrMin(x)
                End If
            End If
        Next x
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: so if I decide I need 4 inputs, I just add a 4th value to each of parameter arrays?  I like it, thanks for the answer.